# What is the aspect ratio and resolution Google Meet prefers?

Tags: google-meet

Recently, I tried emulating a virtual webcam with the Linux kernel `v4l2loopback` (also using OBS Studio v24, if that's important).

While trying to use the emulated webcam with Google Meets, however, the left and right sides were always cropped. I have tried a variety of different aspect ratios and resolutions, all to no avail. Such a desire is feasible, and has worked for me in the past (I lost a config file).

I would appreciate it if anyone had any ideas or advice as to how I could potentially test to see which aspect ratio Google Meet wants, or if anyone has already figured this out (and haven't lost it like me).

(If I find out I will add an update here.)

Thanks!